# error: cannot convert 'const wchar_t [13]' to 'LPCSTR {aka const char*}' in assignment

Tags: c++, winapi, compiler-errors

```
// include the basic windows header file
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>

// the WindowProc function prototype LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd,
                         UINT message,
                         WPARAM wParam,
                         LPARAM lParam);

// the entry point for any Windows program int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                   int nCmdShow) {
    // the handle for the window, filled by a function
    HWND hWnd;
    // this struct holds information for the window class
    WNDCLASSEX wc;

    // clear out the window class for use
    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));

    // fill in the struct with the needed information
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"WindowClass1";

    // register the window class
    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    // create the window and use the result as the handle
    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL,
                          L"WindowClass1",    // name of the window class
                          L"Our First Windowed Program",   // title of the window
                          WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,    // window style
                          300,    // x-position of the window
                          300,    // y-position of the window
                          500,    // width of the window
                          400,    // height of the window
                          NULL,    // we have no parent window, NULL
                          NULL,    // we aren't using menus, NULL
                          hInstance,    // application handle
                          NULL);    // used with multiple windows, NULL

    // display the window on the screen
    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);

    // enter the main loop:

    // this struct holds Windows event messages
    MSG msg;

    // wait for the next message in the queue, store the result in 'msg'
    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        // translate keystroke messages into the right format
        TranslateMessage(&msg);

        // send the message to the WindowProc function
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    // return this part of the WM_QUIT message to Windows
    return msg.wParam; }

// this is the main message handler for the program LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    // sort through and find what code to run for the message given
    switch(message)
    {
        // this message is read when the window is closed
        case WM_DESTROY:
            {
                // close the application entirely
                PostQuitMessage(0);
                return 0;
            } break;
    }

    // Handle any messages the switch statement didn't
    return DefWindowProc (hWnd, message, wParam, lParam); }
```

===============
I use CodeBlock, this code is from a Direct X tutorial.

I get the following errors:

```
||In function 'int WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int)':|
error: cannot convert 'const wchar_t [13]' to 'LPCSTR {aka const char*}' in assignment|
|49|warning: converting to non-pointer type 'DWORD {aka long unsigned int}' from NULL [-Wconversion-null]|
|49|error: cannot convert 'const wchar_t*' to 'LPCSTR {aka const char*}' for argument '2' to 'HWND__* CreateWindowExA(DWORD, LPCSTR, LPCSTR, DWORD, int, int, int, int, HWND, HMENU, HINSTANCE, LPVOID)'|
||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 1 warnings ===|
```

Comment: Are you building for Unicode? Shouldn't you be using `LPCTSTR` instead?

Comment: What do you mean? I prefixed the class name with L so that it uses ANSI instead of the unicode.

Comment: L means wide char strings.

Answer (score 34):

Your project doesn't have the `UNICODE` preprocessor symbol defined, so Windows API functions that take pointers to strings expect `char *` and not `wchar_t *`. Change

```
L"WindowClass1"
```

to

```
"WindowClass1"
```

Do the same for the remaining string literals. Alternatively, change them to `_T("WindowClass1")`, this will expand to the correct type of string literal based on the `UNICODE` symbol being defined.

---

My recommendation is to go to your project properties and change the `Character Set` setting to `Unicode`, and then use the wide char versions of all Windows API functions explicitly. For example, instead of `CreateWindow`, call `CreateWindowW`.

**EDIT:** 
The project setting I suggested only applies to Visual Studio, not sure how to do that in Code::Blocks.

Comment: Not a good idea to call the A and W functions explicity, best to use tchar.h, _T macros and the function names without A or W. It makes it easier to change between compiling with or without UNICODE.

Comment: @user93353 Unless you need to support Windows 95, I don't see a reason to ever switch between the two. Chances are, if you try to support both, you will screw it up somewhere anyway; it's just not worth the trouble, IMHO. I used to have the same opinion as you, until I realized that there wasn't even one instance in all the Windows software I've written where I had to switch Unicode settings.

Comment: @user93353: I agree with Praetorian. There are some new Windows APIs that aren't even *available* in ANSI versions so it is best to just use Unicode always.

Comment: In Visual Studio, I ran the code and got this after compiling it in unicode. The program does run correctly though.

'game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Debug\game.exe', Symbols loaded. 'game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file 'game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file 'game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files\BitDefender\Bitdefender 2013\active virus control\Avc3_00172_012\avcuf32.dll'

Comment: @GladstoneAsder None of those are error messages; the *cannot find PDB* message is just telling you that debugging information for the program was not found but that stuff is not needed for correct functioning. Is your program behaving as expected?

Answer (score 10):

1) If you want to compile with UNICODE, then change the options. If you are compiling from IDE, the set the following propery
Configuration Properties -> General -> Project Defaults -> Character Set -> Use Unicode Character Set.

If compiling from command line use options /DUNICODE /D_UNICODE

If you don't want to compile with UNICODE, just follow steps 2 & 3 below. In Char Set, do not chose UNICODE.

2) Before

```
#include <windows.h>
```

add

```
#include <tchar.h>
```

3) Change

```
wc.lpszClassName = L"WindowClass1";
```

to

```
wc.lpszClassName = _T("WindowClass1");
```

If you want to compile with UNICODE, you could get by just by doing #1, but best to do all 3.

If you want to compile without UNICODE, do #2 & #3 - don't do #1.

Answer (score 10):

I use this on my single source code file because I don't want to change my current project configuration

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#define UNICODE_WAS_UNDEFINED
#endif

#include <Windows.h>

#ifdef UNICODE_WAS_UNDEFINED
#undef UNICODE
#endif
```

Comment: For the code written initially in VS and using wide char strings, I found it easier just to add the missing '#define UNICODE' line for the MinGW GCC.