# Getting a windows text in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, winapi

Hello so recently I have been programming in C++. Please note I compile using -std=c++11 being checked, and use Code::Blocks with MingW compiler because some of the program requires it.

My question is simple: can anyone provide me with a function to get the text of an input bar? I ask this because I cant seem to find working implementations of WM_GETTEXT or GetWindowText.

Edit:

I have these errors:

> ||=== Build: Release in ElitezLua (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
>   C:\Users\PC\Desktop\ElitezLua\Main.cpp||In function 'std::string GetText(HWND, int)':|
>   C:\Users\PC\Desktop\ElitezLua\Main.cpp|35|error: cannot convert 'wchar_t*' to 'LPSTR {aka char*}' for argument '2' to 'int GetWindowTextA(HWND, LPSTR, int)'|
>   ||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 4 second(s)) ===|

Using this code:

```
string GetText(HWND Box, int THN) {
    int Length = GetWindowTextLength(GetDlgItem(Box, THN));
    wchar_t * Text = new wchar_t[Length + 1];
    return GetWindowText(GetDlgItem(Box, THN), Text, (Length + 1));
};
```

(The error is on the return line)

Comment: what user interface are you using?

Comment: What do you mean? I don't understand, being new to programming.

Comment: Uh.. Win32 GUI Project?

Comment: `GetWindowText` is the right way. Show your code so we can see where it goes wrong...

Comment: @Barmak Shemirani Done.

Comment: `return GetWindowText(GetDlgItem(Box, THN), Text, (Length + 1));` this doesn't return string

Comment: The text you need is in `Text`

Comment: You re getting an error because function has string return type and you return int

Comment: I fixed that but now how do I read from it if its an int? I'm so confused.

Comment: The text you need is in `Text`.

Comment: Wait I will edit and add the function

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with `GetWindowText`. The problem is that [you are passing Unicode information when your project is set for non-Unicode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977388/error-cannot-convert-const-wchar-t-13-to-lpcstr-aka-const-char-in-assi). Change your project to Unicode and you'll be fine.

Comment: Stop using crappy tools. Code::Blocks still defaults to MBCS character encoding. In 2016! Better tools are available at [Free Dev Tools - Visual Studio Community 2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx). For the time being, call the explicit API version (wide character vs. ANSI), i.e. `GetWindowTextW` instead of `GetWindowText`.

Answer (score 1):

```
string GetText(HWND Box, int THN) 
{
    int Length = GetWindowTextLength(GetDlgItem(Box, THN));
    wchar_t * Text = new wchar_t[Length + 1];
    return GetWindowText(GetDlgItem(Box, THN), Text, (Length + 1));
};
```

There are several errors in above code:

- 1st, mixing ANSI/Unicode
- 2nd, memory leak due to `new char_t[]`.
- 3rd, returning `int` when `std::string` is expected.

Let's start by something simple:

```
wchar_t Text[300] = {0};
GetWindowTextW(GetDlgItem(Box, THN), Text, 300);
MessageBoxW(0, Text, 0, 0);
```

This should always work, as long text length is less than 300 (otherwise it's chopped) This is good enough to get button names, or to get text from a small edit box.

The `W` at the end of functions forces Unicode. Or you can add `#define UNICODE` on top of cpp file.

```
#define UNICODE
#include <Windows.h>

...
int len = GetWindowTextLen(GetDlgItem(Box, THN));
if (len > 0)
{
    //add 1 for null-terminating char
    len += 1; 
    wchar_t Text *new wchar_t[len];
    GetWindowText(GetDlgItem(Box, THN), Text, len);
    MessageBox(0, Text, 0, 0);
    delete[]Text;
}
```

Next, you can put this in a function to return `std::wstring`

```
std::wstring foo()
{
    std::wstring::str;
    int len = GetWindowTextLen(GetDlgItem(Box, THN));
    if (len > 0)
    {
        len += 1; 
        wchar_t Text *new wchar_t[len];
        GetWindowText(GetDlgItem(Box, THN), Text, len);
        str = text;
        delete[]Text;
    }
    return str;
}
```

Once you get the hang of this you can use `std::wstring` directly:

```
std::wstring foo()
{
    int len = 1 + GetWindowTextLength(GetDlgItem(Box, THN));

    //initialize a string large enough to read data
    std::wstring str(len, L'\0');
    GetWindowText(GetDlgItem(Box, THN), &str[0], len);
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First get the length of the text:

```
int l = GetWindowTextLength(GetDlgItem(hWnd, ID_OF_YOUR_CONTROL));
```

Now get the text (`hWnd` is the handler of the window that holds the control):

```
wchar_t* txt = new wchar_t[l + 1];
GetWindowText(GetDlgItem(hWnd, ID_OF_YOUR_CONTROL), txt, l + 1);
```

I hope this will help you

Edit ------

```
std::wstring GetText(HWND Box, int THN) {
    int Length = GetWindowTextLength(GetDlgItem(Box, THN));
    wchar_t * Text = new wchar_t[Length + 1];
    GetWindowText(GetDlgItem(Box, THN), Text, (Length + 1));
    return wstring(Text);
};
```

Comment: string GetText(HWND Box) {
    int Length = GetWindowTextLength(GetDlgItem(Box, InputBar));
    wchar_t * Text = new wchar_t[Length + 1];
    return GetWindowText(GetDlgItem(Box, InputBar), Text, (Length + 1));
};                                                                                                                                            Why doesn't it work?

Comment: What you mean it doesn't work? And what are the `Box` and `InputBar`?

Comment: Box is the TextBox to get the text from (Do you need the code from it?) and InputBar is the (HMENU)Number I used for detecting when they are clicked.

Comment: I get these errors: ||=== Build: Release in ElitezLua (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Users\PC\Desktop\ElitezLua\Main.cpp||In function 'std::string GetText(HWND, int)':|
C:\Users\PC\Desktop\ElitezLua\Main.cpp|35|error: cannot convert 'wchar_t*' to 'LPSTR {aka char*}' for argument '2' to 'int GetWindowTextA(HWND, LPSTR, int)'|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 4 second(s)) ===|
     on line 35 (the return line)

Comment: Please update your question and add some code, so I can help you more

Comment: Btw, ` return GetWindowText(GetDlgItem(Box, InputBar), Text, (Length + 1));` this doesn't return string

Comment: I sort of realized that was the error, but I haven't an idea how to convert it to one.

Comment: Also add `delete[] Text` before exit

Comment: How does this address the problem of mixing explicit Unicode strings with generic text mappings, that happen to expand to MBCS strings?