# WINDOWS api can't resolve external symbol

Tags: c++, winapi, compilation

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

```
#define _x64

#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windef.h>
#include <Winuser.h>
#include <tchar.h>
using namespace std;

int WINAPI MessageBoxW(
    _In_opt_ HWND    hWnd,
    _In_opt_ LPCTSTR lpText,
    _In_opt_ LPCTSTR lpCaption,
    _In_     UINT    uType
);

int main(){
    std::cout << MessageBoxW(NULL, L"", L"", 0);
}
```

I am using compiling with Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.00.24215.1 and using the "/EHsc" option at the command line for a command line input of "cl /EHsc winbasicb.cpp". I am not doing anything fancy I feel. Just using the /EHsc option for optimized compilation and linking.

I am getting this error.

```
/out:winbasicb.exe
winbasicb.obj
winbasicb.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_MessageBoxW referenced in function main 
winbasicb.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I have read [error: cannot convert 'const wchar_t [13]' to 'LPCSTR {aka const char*}' in assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13977388/4284627), but that was not helpful because they're getting a compiler error but I'm getting a linker error. In that question, the error was due to using `MessageBoxW(..., "", "", ...)` instead of `MessageBoxW(..., L"", L"", ...)`, but I used `L""` as I should but I'm getting a linker error.

Comment: `L"..."` signifies a unicode string.

Comment: I encountered the same linker error.  Since someone decided to close this question, I'll answer it in a comment.  Project Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies > Edit > Enable checkbox "Inherit from parent or project defaults".  This will result in a addition of many Windows .lib files e.g. "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib".

Comment: @DavidHeffernan This is not a duplicate. The other question asks about a compiler error due to using `char*` instead of `wchar_t*`, but in this case they're using `wchar_t*` as they should and they're getting a linker error.

Answer (score 3):

In Windows there are two versions of just about all Windows API functions.

If you see the "Requirements" section of [this reference page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx) you will see that there is one `MessageBoxW` and one `MessageBoxA` function. The symbol `MessageBox` is a macro defined as one of the actual functions depending on the `UNICODE` macro.

The `MessageBoxW` function expects the strings to be wide-character strings, which is what you pass. Unfortunately it seem you don't have the correct Unicode settings, so the ANSI (narrow character, plain `char`) version `MessageBoxA` is used instead.

There are two solutions: Either make sure you have the correct Unicode settings. Or by explicitly call `MessageBoxW`. Or don't use wide-character strings (i.e. drop the `L` prefix).

Comment: My compiler uses UTF-8 by default. So I rewrote this in notepad an saved it as ANSI but still says the types are incompatible. I tried MessageBoxA and MessageBoxW likewise. Still can't compile.

Comment: @1911Soldier Have you tried passing narrow-character strings instead? You do that by not using the `L` prefix for the strings.

Comment: *"there are two versions of just about all Windows API functions"* - That's not correct. Only API functions with string arguments have two versions, with a few exceptions (e.g. [GetProcAddress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212.aspx) only has a narrow string version, or [ReadDirectoryChangesW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465.aspx), which only has a wide character version).

Comment: @1911Soldier: You are using Microsoft's compiler, and cl.exe doesn't use UTF-8 by default. While it *can* digest UTF-8 encoded source files (see [Unicode Support in the Compiler and Linker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwy0e8f2.aspx)), those have to have an explicit BOM. Besides, the source character set used by the compiler is unrelated to the error you get.

Comment: Also the ANSI versions of the functions do not support UTF-8. You have to use the Unicode functions (which use UTF-16). If you need to convert, use `MultiByteToWideChar()` and friends.

Comment: I removed the L precuser preceding arg 1 and 3 and converted the function from an int function to a wchar_t function and put c style casts on arg 2 and 3 in this format '(LPCSTR)'. And now I am getting this error.

Comment: c:\Users\headgearxthree\Documents\res_bin>cl /EHsc sdbox.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.24215.1 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

sdbox.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.00.24215.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:sdbox.exe
sdbox.obj
sdbox.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__MessageBoxA@16 referenced in function "int __cdecl DisplayConfirmSaveAsMessageBox(void)" (?DisplayConfirmSaveAsMessageBox@@YAHXZ)
sdbox.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Comment: Honestly. Why not use a web search engine. You are going to be stuck in the slow lane unless you learn to research.

Comment: I revised my question, maybe you can help now.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Using `char*` instead of `wchar_t*` or vice-versa would produce a compiler error. In this case they're using the correct one and getting a linker error.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `TCHAR` version of `MessageBox()`. The conversion error message is complaining that you are passing Unicode strings to `MessageBoxA()`, which expects Ansi strings instead.  This means your project is being compiled without `UNICODE` defined, thus `TCHAR` maps to `char` and `MessageBox()` maps to `MessageBoxA()`.  But the `L` prefix is used to create Unicode literals, not Ansi literals.

When passing string literals to `TCHAR` based functions, use the `TEXT()` macro to ensure proper character encoding:

```
int msgboxID = MessageBox(
    NULL,
    TEXT("temp.txt already exists.\nDo you want to replace it?"),
    TEXT("Confirm Save As"),
    MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_YESNO
 );
```

Otherwise, stay away from the `TCHAR` functions (`TCHAR` should only be used when compiling the same codebase for both Win9x/ME and NT4+ Windows families), use the Ansi or Unicode functions directly instead:

```
int msgboxID = MessageBoxA(
    NULL,
    "temp.txt already exists.\nDo you want to replace it?",
    "Confirm Save As",
    MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_YESNO
 );
```

```
int msgboxID = MessageBoxW(
    NULL,
    L"temp.txt already exists.\nDo you want to replace it?",
    L"Confirm Save As",
    MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_YESNO
 );
```

Comment: I can compile it like this

Comment: <code>#include<Windows.h>
#include<windowsx.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<tchar.h>
using namespace std;

int WINAPI MessageBoxW(
  _In_opt_ HWND    hWnd,
  _In_opt_ LPCTSTR lpText,
  _In_opt_ LPCTSTR lpCaption,
  _In_     UINT    uType
);
int main(){

}</code>