# GETTING THE ERROR IN VISUAL STUDIO: error C2664: '_chmod' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'wchar_t [260]' to 'const char *'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, delete-file, msdn

C++ code to delete any folder:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <afx.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <io.h>

using namespace std;

BOOL IsDots(wchar_t* str)
{
    if (_tcscmp(str, TEXT(".")) && _tcscmp(str, TEXT("..")))
        return FALSE;
    return TRUE;
}

BOOL DeleteDirectory(wchar_t* sPath)
{
    HANDLE hFind;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;

    wchar_t DirPath[MAX_PATH];
    wchar_t FileName[MAX_PATH];

    _tcscpy(DirPath, sPath);
    _tcscat(DirPath, TEXT("\\*"));
    _tcscpy(FileName, sPath);
    _tcscat(FileName, TEXT("\\"));

    //GETTING THE FISRT FILE

    hFind = FindFirstFile(DirPath, &FindFileData);
    if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return FALSE;
    _tcscpy(DirPath, FileName);

    bool bSearch = true;
    while (bSearch) {
        if (FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData)) {

            if (IsDots(FindFileData.cFileName))
                continue;

            _tcscat(FileName, FindFileData.cFileName);
            if ((FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)) {

                //DELETING THE DIRECTORY

                if (!DeleteDirectory(FileName)) {
                    FindClose(hFind);
                    return FALSE;
                }
                RemoveDirectory(FileName);
                _tcscpy(FileName, DirPath);
            }

            else {

                if (FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY)
                    _chmod(FileName, _S_IWRITE);
                mode if (!DeleteFile(FileName))
                {
                    FindClose(hFind);
                    return FALSE;
                }

                _tcscpy(FileName, DirPath);
            }
        }

        else {
            if (GetLastError() == ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
                bSearch = false;
            else {

                FindClose(hFind);
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
    }
    FindClose(hFind);

    return RemoveDirectory(sPath);
}

//CALLING THE DEL DIR FUNCTION
```

HOPE ANYONE COULD HELP!!

I get the following error:

> error C2664: '_chmod' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'wchar_t
>   [260]' to 'const char *'

P.S. I use Microsoft Visual Studio.

Comment: I think the error is pretty obvious. You have an array of `wchar_t` and try to call a function which expects an array of `char`. This is probably due to a mismatch between your `UNICODE` macro settings and that `_chmod` is a non-standard function that doesn't come in wide- and narrow-character alternatives. Try using a Windows API function instead, or [`_wchmod`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z319a54.aspx).

Comment: Please stop shouting.

Comment: _wchmod worked thnx a lot :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Please answer in the answer section, not in the comments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: cannot convert 'const wchar\_t \[13\]' to 'LPCSTR {aka const char\*}' in assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977388/error-cannot-convert-const-wchar-t-13-to-lpcstr-aka-const-char-in-assi)

Comment: Also note that this recursive approach, which works fine on POSIX systems, won't work reliably on Windows.  When `DeleteFile` returns, the file may not yet actually be deleted, so when you then try to remove its directory, that can fail because the directory isn't empty (yet).  For details, see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uhRWMGBjlO8 (relevant portion starts about 7:35).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using *wide characters*, but calling the *narrow character* version of the function.

Most Windows API functions [transparently switch between the two](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374089(v=vs.85).aspx) by virtue of the `UNICODE` macro being set. The "chmod" function with this behaviour is [`_tchmod`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z319a54.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

**You should switch to `_tchmod`.**

Comment: I highly recommend reading the documentation pages I've linked to.